# Yii CDbCriteria error: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have a problem.

I use the `ext.ecolumns.EColumnsDialog` and when in these fields enters a value filter it works fine, except for id. When you type anything at id, whether true or false it receives something on the principle of `alert ()` coming from javascript. This alert contains the text:

```
Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `table_test` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `two_table` `twotables` ON (`t`.`two_table`=`twotables`.`id`)  LEFT OUTER .....
```

How can I fix this error? I tried to add now 
 `$criteria->compare('t.id', $this->id);` or similar.

EDIT1:
my controller file:

```
$model = new Model_name('search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

        if (isset($_GET['Model_name'])){

            $model->attributes = $_GET['Model_name'];


}
        $this->render('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
```

my Model file:

```
 public function search()
        {
     $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

 $criteria->addCondition("t.id=:id");
$criteria->params = array(":id"=>$this->id);
    ....

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => $sort,
            'pagination' => $pages
        ));
```

I changed Model name and controller because doesn't wish to disclose:)

Answer (score 0):

That error is thrown when you are trying to reference a field where the field could belong to multiple tables you're selecting from, due to a missing table name or alias before the field.

Hard to tell without the entire query or without all of the CDBcriteria code. I'd try using the table name explicitly.

```
$criteria->compare('table_test.id', $this->id);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a primaryKey as a safe attribute as it's not something that should ever really change. By the looks of your search function you're trying to get the id from a form that you're searching on. 

Searching via a primary key will only ever return one result so using the search action for this is not correct. I'm going to guess now that the error is due to id being empty. Solution: Don't search via id.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`$criteria->addCondition()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) **with binding parameter** instead of `$criteria->compare()` as following:

```
$criteria->addCondition("t.id=:id");
$criteria->params = array(":id"=>$this->id);
```

You can replace all "compare" with "addCondition".

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? Still "Integrity constraint violation" error, or another problem?

Comment: Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(

Comment: I had same problem before and I solved it by using `addCondition` instead of `compare`. I searched for your problem, but nothing found. This problem is very strange for me. Can you post code of your models?